# Hight temperiture sealant

Tags: gas, sealant

There is a inch-long crack between the burner and the surface of my stove top and there is gas leaking out when the stove is turn on.  My contractor said that the sealant got burn off. What can I use to seal it back so it would leak gas?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This does not sound like something to mess around with.  I would have it repaired by a qualified appliance repair professional, or have it replaced.

Comment: Wait, what? (proofreading aside) What's the model # of your stove? Did it come with a crack like that, or are you trying to re-do some previous hack job, which is likely to lead to the same problem in the future? I've never seen any type of sealant on a burner assembly. I don't think NASA re-uses heat shields... so, even if you do find a high temperature sealant, I doubt it's supposed to be continually exposed to flame. Then again, SE has surprised me in the past, but IMO the only thing that'd work would be asbestos (*not* recommended; see comment above).

Comment: thx.  It is a 30-inch Maytag, a few year-old.  It is the first time this happened. it is not exposed to flame--it is about 3/4 inch under the flame (between the burner and the surface of the gas range). Any more thoughts?...